# d3.js find top and bottom limits of quantize scale

Tags: d3.js

I've made a map in d3 that is tinted my values, so I've got:

```
var color= d3.scale.quantize().range(["#FAE3C3", "#EBAD95","#DB7768", "#CC403A", "#BC0A0C"]);
```

How does one find the actual limits of the scale, so I can create the map key? (I'd want it to update if I fed in new data).

Comment: Do you mean the [domain](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantize_domain)?

Comment: At what values the domain is divided up between the 'bins'.  I'm now using (max - min )/ 5, but I'm getting values that don't quite add up to the total.  Also realizing it would make more sense to set tidier breakpoints anyhow...no-one wants to read a key of 552346-4500394.

Comment: You'll have to make sure that's the case yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can get back the lower and upper bounds for a bin like so:

`var bounds = color.invertExtent('#FAE3C3')`

A possible solution for a legend would be to iterate through the color array and call `color.invertExtent` for each color.

If you want tidier breakpoints, I think you have to define them yourself and set them as the domain, for example if your minimum is 2 and your maximum is 59 you could do the following:

```
color= d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range(["#FAE3C3", "#EBAD95","#DB7768", "#CC403A", "#BC0A0C"]);
```

so that `maximum - minumum` is divisible by the number of colors.